# Cannot navigate in django url smoothly

Tags: python, django, url, menu

I am making a web app in django ,i have set the url path in "urls" file of the app and also set views but the problem is that **when i click the menu items once it works , now when i am on that page  when i click it some other button or even reclick the same menu option it gives an error** , it seems like its not routing properly . i have to go back to home and then go to some other url...

when first time i click menu item ( http://localhost:3000/chest/ ) route sets like this.

when i click menu item in the new page it appends to the route like this 
( http://localhost:3000/chest/bicep ) instead of this ( http://localhost:3000/bicep/ ).

**Code:**

**urls.py**

## from django.contrib import admin

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
# from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name = "HOME"),
    path("blog_detail/<int:id>", views.blog_detail, name = "blog"),
    # path("about/", views.about, name="about"),
    # path("contact/", views.contact, name="contact"),
    path("back/", views.back1, name="back"),
    # re_path(r'^back/$', views.back1, name="back"),
    path("chest/", views.chest, name="chest"),
    path("shoulder/",views.shoulder, name="shoulder"),
    path("abs/", views.abs, name="abs"),
    path("bicep/", views.bicep, name="bicep"),
    path("tricep/", views.tricep, name= "tricep"),
    path("forearm/", views.forearm, name="forearm"),
    path("legs/", views.legs, name="legs"),
    path("fullbody/", views.fullbody, name="fullbody"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search"),

]



**views.py**


from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# from .models import Blogpost
# from fitness_blog.models import *
from .models import leg
from .models import chest1
from .models import back
from .models import fullbody1
from .models import bicep1
from .models import tricep1
from .models import shoulder1
from .models import forearm1
from .models import abs1
from .models import chest1
from .models import leg
from .models import shoulder1
from .models import tricep1
from .models import bicep1
from .models import forearm1
from .models import fullbody1
from .models import Blogpost
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
# Create your views here.




def home(request):
    post1 = reversed(Blogpost.objects.all())
    # print(post1)
    # post1.reverse()
    print(post1)
    return render(request,"blog/index.html", {'post':post1})


def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search')
    all_blogs= Blogpost.objects.all()
    searched_blogs=[]
    for item in all_blogs:
        word= item.title.lower().split()

        if query in word:
            searched_blogs.append(item)
            print(item.title, "this is filtered.........Mubarak button is working....!!!!!!!!!!!")
    for t in searched_blogs:
        print(t, "from the list")

    print(query)
    # for items in all_blogs:
        # split_items = items.split(" ")
    # print(query, a)
    if len(searched_blogs) != 0:

        return render(request, "blog/search.html", {'post': searched_blogs, "length":len(searched_blogs)})
    else:
        print("it is reaching here")
        return render(request, "blog/not_found.html", {"length":len(searched_blogs)})



def blog_detail(request, id):
    # Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 4, 7])
    blog = Blogpost.objects.filter(post_id=id)[0]
    return render(request,"blog/blog_detail.html", {"blog": blog})

def chest(request):
    post2 = chest1.objects.all()[0]
    # print(post2.post_id)
    return render(request, "blog/chests.html", {'post': post2})

def legs(request):
    post = leg.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/legs.html", {'post': post})


def back1(request):
    post = back.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/legs.html", {'post': post})


def fullbody(request):
    post = fullbody1.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/full-body.html", {'post': post})


def bicep(request):
    post = bicep1.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/bicep.html", {'post': post})


def tricep(request):
    post = tricep1.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/bicep.html", {'post': post})


def shoulder(request):
    post = shoulder1.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/shoulder.html", {'post': post})

def forearm(request):
    post = forearm1.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/forearm.html", {'post': post})

def abs(request):
    post = abs1.objects.all()[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, "blog/abs.html", {'post': post})


**"basic.html file"which extends on very page of webapp**


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Gym Crunch</title>
  </head>








<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0"></script>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0"></script>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0"></script>
  <style>

    .img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}


  </style>
    {% load static %}
  <body style="background-image: url('{% static 'blog/background.jpg' %}');">
    <div class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Brutal-Lifting</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="chest" onclick="goBack()">chest</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="back">back</a>
                </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="shoulder">shoulder</a>
                </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="abs">ABS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="bicep">bicep</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="tricep">tricep</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="legs">legs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="forearm">forearm</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="fullbody">Full-Body</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>



  {% block body %} {% endblock %}






        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i repeat the problem is that the **url in the browser dont updates but it appends the url** like this: **http://localhost:3000/chest/bicep** instead of updating like this: http://localhost:3000/bicep/

thank you i hope this information is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of your links in HTML, use `url` tag, instead of `href='bicep'` write `href={% url 'bicep' %}` etc.

---

Look at the name of your url path:

path("bicep/", views.bicep, **name="bicep"**)

You need to put **this name** to `url` tag. 
If you want to use primary key - you are doing it wrong. At first you need to make new url pattern like:

```
path('blog_detail/<int:pk>', views.*viewname*, name='blog-detail')
```

and then you specify the primary key (pk) which is usually an id of the object in the `url` tag. For example you are creating links to your posts (but first create listview of course):

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog-detail' pk=post.id %}">
```

Comment: <a href={% url 'blog_detail/{{item.post_id}}' %} class="btn btn-primary">read more...</a>... now this is giving a NoReverseMatch error ....

Comment: No-no, you should use `names` of your url patterns, that you define in urls.py

Comment: i urls.py route is path("blog_detail/<int:id>", views.blog_detail, name = "blog"), in views the function is this : def blog_detail(request, id):
    # Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 4, 7])
    blog = Blogpost.objects.filter(post_id=id)[0]
    return render(request,"blog/blog_detail.html", {"blog": blog})  ............ and in html file the route is  <a href={% url 'blog_detail/item.post_id>' %} class="btn btn-primary">read more...</a>........   they are actually grid of articles on home page

Comment: basically i want to open a particular blog when it it clicked that is why i am adding a post_id in html

Comment: check my answer, it's too big for a comment